# How can you localize drawable-nodpi?

Tags: android, localization

The documentation seems to imply you can't do localization AND resolution targetting.

Can anyone tell me how you can go about localizing drawable-nodpi?

Eclipse returns an invalid resource directory name error.

I'm targeting Android 2.2 only so if there are more recent ways to solve this, would be great to hear about them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the answer is, rather than pathing with drawable-nodpi-de-rDE you put drawable-de-rDE-nodpi.

Format:
{resource}-{language}-r{region}-{resolution}

Documentation is particularly lacking in examples.

Answer (score 1):

At First, Run Time Executing drawable folder's(like  `drawable-ldpi`,`drawable-nodpi`,`values-long`,etc) are supports in Android 1.6 or later version only. if you want support your app which has developed using Android 1.5. you have to note `-v` which is in the [Strategies for Legacy Applications](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) topic

Comment: Thanks, legacy applications aren't an issue for me, it's just getting both resolution qualifiers and localization qualifiers to work.